# Zend Framework 2: how to get columns from joined tables?

Tags: php, mysql, join, zend-framework2

I am using Zend Framework 2.4 with `TableGateway` and need to execute the following query:

```
SELECT products.title, student.firstname, orders.order_id, 
  orders.profile_id, orders.status
FROM student 
INNER JOIN 
 (products 
   INNER JOIN orders ON products.product_id = orders.product_id) 
     ON student.student_id = orders.student_id 
WHERE (((orders.profile_id)='.$id.'));
```

Here is what I am using:

```
$select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();
$select->columns(array('*'))
        ->join('products', 'products.product_id = orders.product_id', array('title'))
        ->join('student', 'student.student_id = orders.student_id', array('first_name'))
        ->where(array('orders.profile_id' => $id));
$items = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
return $items;
```

The problem is that `$items` does not contain the columns `title` or `first_name`. It only contains the columns from the orders table.
What do I need to do to get `$items` to contain the columns from the joined tables?

Comment: Funny, look at this post: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245636/zend-db-join-selects-all-columns** This person has exactly the opposite problem, so essentially your solution (do not add columns(array)))

Comment: I have tried it without the columns(array('*')). No change, title & first_name are still not members of $items.

Comment: `$this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();` : What is your base query? You probably have to start with a `->from('orders',array with columns)` in your query here to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: The tableGateway is on the orders table. I tried ->from('orders', array(bla bla bla)). It caused the following error - "Since this object was created with a table and/or schema in the constructor, it is read only."

Comment: You will have to start the query from scratch....

Answer (score 0):

try to use an associative array

```
$select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();
$select->columns(array('*'))
    ->join('products', 'products.product_id = orders.product_id', array('title' => 'product_title'))
    ->join('student', 'student.student_id = orders.student_id', array('first_name' => 'student_first_name'))
    ->where(array('orders.profile_id' => $id));
$items = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
return $items;
```